# Programmatically get the result of a GitlabCI Job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to create a script which takes the result of a CI job and if it succeeded launches some other testing on that repository.

The problem is that gitlab api doesn't support getting the Job's output. Let alone a success/failure flag.
I tried to use webdriver to get the content of the `<div>` containing the results. However, the urls leading to the jobs aren't incremental in a predictable way. It depends on how many jobs exist overall and where in the queue this job has been placed. Here's an example how such a job url looks like

`http://<glab_url>/<user>/<project>/-/jobs/25`

25 being the overall job id

The other idea is to make webdriver click through the UI until we get to the specified job, however this seems inefficient.

Has anybody faced this problem before? If so how did you solve it?

//edit: Providing some context after @vladkras's useful answer.
// We have multiple dev teams, devs are encouraged to create their own projects. I don't have any control over who runs what in a CI. I just want to add some basic checks for security, known bad patterns and secrets in repos that build successfully. These checks should just report to me/my team for now and if the project succeeds then we will discuss about bothering developers into integrating it.

Comment: I see your edit. But it's not clear anyway: 1. how can you know job id (it increases every time) 2. if you want to test code in another repo just clone it and test

Comment: I can't just clone it and test because ideally I need to do this for 2k repos. Manually would take ages. I need to somehow know which repos had recent successful builds so I can only filter out the ones who are both active and building

Comment: You still need thousands of projects ids. Do you have them? How about combination of `GET /projects` and `GET /projects/:id/pipelines?status=success` or `GET /projects/:id/jobs?scope[]=success` from [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html)

Comment: I got the projects with the GET /projects you mentioned, hadn't thought of the second part. Thanks man, can you add it to your question so I can accept it?

Comment: You're welcome! Updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your architecture. If you need "to do something when pipeline succeed" - just add it as one more job. It will never run if previous one fails.

And you can use [dependencies](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#dependencies) to access result of previous job, e.g.:

```
job1:
  artifacts:
    paths:
     - test
  script:
   - echo "result" > test/file
job2:
  dependencies:
    job1
  script:
   - cat test/file
```

EDIT

API solution how to get all CI pipelines and jobs that succeeded:

GET /projects

GET [/projects/:id/pipelines?status=success](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html)

GET [/projects/:id/jobs?scope[]=success](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html)

Comment: Good idea and I will do this if nothing else works, however, i don't have any control over ci jobs. I will need to bother people into adding my scripts in  their pipelines and this is inflexible and we'd like to avoid it